# Why image not shown fully, because of float, or image above?

Tags: html, css, image, class, css-float

I want that text2 stands next to image3 on the left side in the middle, but unfortunately its not shown fully and goes visually under image2. It has something to do with the float tag in the css code or the image 2 above but i dont know whats the problem, would be nice if someone could help :)
This is my html code;

```css
.image2{
      width: 1917px;
      height: 523px;
    }


    .imagetwo{
      width: 1917px;
      height: 523px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      position:absolute;
    }



    .button1{
      position:absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: #212f40;
      color:white;
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 12px 24px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 400px;
      height: 90px;
    }

    .button1:hover {
      background-color:#911e46;
    }


    .image3{
      float:right; 
      margin-left: 5em;
      width: 905x;
      height: 590px;
    }

    .imagethree .text2{
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      margin-left:40px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      color: white !important;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
.<div class="imagetwo">
  <img class="image2" src="https://pixabay.com/de/photos/erbse-erbsen-gem%C3%BCse-gr%C3%BCn-1205673/">
  <button class="button1">Jetzt informieren </button>
</div>

<div class="imagethree">
  <img class="image3" src="https://pixabay.com/de/photos/aufsicht-closeup-vegetarismus-1248949/">
  <div class="text2">
    <h1>Lass dich beraten</h1>
    <p>Wir geben unser bestes für jeden Einzelnen.</p><br>
    <p>Ich begleite dich auf dem Weg zu mehr Wohlbefinden...
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br>
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat <br>
    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
    <br>
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <br>
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
    </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please edit your code to contain the correct link to images so we can reproduce the issue. Also use a code snippet (Ctrl + M) so we can actually run this snippet.

Comment: The image cant be floated at the right side of the text teh way you coded it. The image is wrapped inside a div creating a new block level element. By default, block elements will be displayed below each other. To have the image floated at the right of the text, it should be within the same wrapper as the `text2 wrapper`. Alternativly you can sue flexbox or css-grid. However, the image will not be floated that way but displayed "column-like" next to each other.

Comment: PS: Last but not least, you have a lot of invalid HTML. `<h1>`header tag should not be within a paragraph `<p>` tag. YOu miss many paragrapgh closing tags `</p>`. Also if you give your pragraph tags a class, then there is no reason to use a linebreak `<br>` afterwards as you could achieve the same with a `margin-bottom`.

Comment: thank you very much i edit the code and made the snippet with the correct links. can you give an example code for solving this with the gird function for example? And when you mentioned flexbox did you mean that i should but all the image in one flexbox and position them with justify content for example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex to accomplish this, floats get a little tricky to deal with because take the elements out of the flow from the DOM

wrap your text and image with div sampe below

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  max-width:500px;/*can set a with so it does not expand full with*/
  margin:auto; /*center it on the page*/
}

.text{
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.image{ width:100px; height:100px } /*optional image size*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="text">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>I'm baby letterpress art party beard normcore +1 DIY truffaut leggings jean shorts photo booth. Hoodie palo santo letterpress iPhone occupy pickled normcore. Cardigan schlitz occupy letterpress tattooed normcore wolf leggings iPhone vape locavore truffaut coloring book lumbersexual bicycle rights. Tacos echo park letterpress salvia vexillologist listicle kitsch lumbersexual hammock pinterest occupy post-ironic. Food truck pop-up farm-to-table copper mug pabst iPhone twee XOXO YOLO messenger bag polaroid vinyl ethical vegan retro.</p>
</div>

<img class="image" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/554/200/200.jpg?hmac=wvBDWVN6iXLUYv4DYpQ9fWSg_2y3dCYyzy4N_6H26pY" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you ...if i put the code like this  the image goes very far right and a part of the image is not shown ( under the image above) and the text also (the upper part is nt shown?

Comment: the image is not getting cut off that's how the image is it just looks like that way. if you don't want for the content to go all the way across, you can set width or max-width to the wrapper, and if you need it to be center on the page horizontal add a margin:auto

Answer (score 0):

If you use float, give the image a width. Otherwise it will show at its full size (if the image is 4000px wide, it will be displayed with a width of 4000px and proberly overflow every screen. This is how float actually works:

```css
.image3{
  float: right; 
  margin-left: 5em;
  width: 50%;
}


.text2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<img class="image3" src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">


<div class="text2">
  <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
  <p class="one1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><br>
  <p class="two1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <br>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to use CSS-Grid, then the image wont be floated but in a column next to the etxt and the text will only stay it its own column. However you need to wrap the text and the image and should palce the image below the text (HTML wise)

```css
.image3 {
  width: 100%;
}

.text2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text2">
    <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
    <p class="one1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p><br>
    <p class="two1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>

  <img class="image3" src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
</div>
```